# Flurry Push Notifications in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I'm using Flurry to try to send push notifications, the tutorial for all other elements of Flurry like analytics, events etc all have Swift and Obj-C however for Push its all in Obj-C.

I've got the flurry ios sdk added and everything works well because I can see my data on the flurry site.

I'm stuck at this point when it tells me to

> Include FlurryMessaging.h

How do I include a .h file in Swift?

It then asks me to do the following but its not in Swift

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Step1 : Call the Integration API

[FlurryMessaging setAutoIntegrationForMessaging];

//Step2 (Optional): Get a callback

[FlurryMessaging setMessagingDelegate:self];

FlurrySessionBuilder* builder = [[[FlurrySessionBuilder alloc] withIncludeBackgroundSessionsInMetrics:YES];

[Flurry startSession:@”API_KEY” withOptions:launchOptions withSessionBuilder:builder];

return YES;

}

Implement the Delegate method for Received
-(void) didReceiveMessage:(nonnull FlurryMessage*)message

{

NSLog(@”didReceiveMessage = %@”, [message description]);

//App specific implementation

}

Implement the Delegate method for Clicked
-(void) didReceiveActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString*)identifier message:(nonnull FlurryMessage*)message

{

NSLog(@”didReceiveAction %@ , Message = %@”,identifier, [message description]);

//Any app specific logic goes here.

//Ex: Deeplink logic (loading of viewControllers (nibs or storboards),

//additional logging, etc

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are integrating through Cocoapods, make sure to include ‘Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging’in your podfile. If you have, then you can access the Messaging methods by adding this to your import statements:

import Flurry_iOS_SDK

Then set auto integration:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

FlurryMessaging.setAutoIntegrationForMessaging()
FlurryMessaging.setMessagingDelegate(self)

//And set up your Builder:

let builder = FlurrySessionBuilder.init()

    .withIncludeBackgroundSessionsInMetrics(true)

Flurry.startSession("YOUR_API_KEY", with: builder)
return true
}
```

Implement the Delegate method for Received

```
func didReceive(_ message: FlurryMessage) {
    print("Did Receive Message")
    //App specific implementation
}
```

Implement the Delegate method for Clicked

```
func didReceiveAction(withIdentifier identifier: String?, message: FlurryMessage) {
    print("Message Clicked")
    //Any app specific logic goes here.
}
```